# Codes are not executed sequentially regarding threading and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "";
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("111");
            }
            System.err.println("Waiting for s");
            synchronized (s) {
                System.err.println("got s");
            }
            System.out.println("last");
        }
    };

    t.start();
    synchronized (s) {
        t.interrupt();
        s.notifyAll();
    }


    try {
        Thread.currentThread()
              .sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("222");

}
```

The output is always:

```
111

last

Waiting for s

got s

222

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand how could the 'last' get printed before 'waiting for s' and 'got s'??
(why the lines are not executed sequentially?)

Comment: `System.out` and `System.err` are different output streams. They are not guaranteed to be interleaved in the console in the order they are written to.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yours makes since! 
I changed to all output to use System.out, and they print out sequentially.

I guess I didn't know the root cause of this issue, I thought this was related to multi-threading